# How can I test my Unity Android projects on various API levels

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arm, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have Android Studio setup with multiple AVDs but they are all x86. I'm currently working on a 2D Unity project and it will not run on these AVDs. if I'm reading the error correctly, the device needs to be able to run arm but my Intel computer cannot run an arm AVD. it's so slow that it cannot be used and often freezes for minutes at a time. This has been tested on a 9900K with a GTX 1070 with hardware acceleration and VT-x turned on.

The Device simulator in unity will solve the problem of looking at how the project gets displayed on various resolutions but it doesn't solve the issue of running the app on all the android versions from the minimum API level.

I only have 2 physical devices available for this and I can use Unity remote 5 also with no issues but I often read about people having issues where the app crashes on certain android versions and I would like to fix that issue before my users experience it.

some people also recommend using something like Bluestacks or Nox but I don't think I can change the OS version it uses, can I?

all I currently still need on this is emulators that can be set up with the android version I need in order to test the app.

Also, will arm7 images on an AVD solve this problem? if so, how can I run one smoothly on an intel system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cloud app testing services.
Google has one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab

There is a good overview here:
https://adtmag.com/blogs/dev-watch/2017/05/device-clouds.aspx

One that is not mentioned though is [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/android-testing)

As far as Bluestacks or Nox goes, they will not perform much better than the default emulator when using ARM I'm afraid.

Happy Testing!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.